# Saving game score using javascript cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

I am trying to save the end game score of this tetris game linked in the patebin below as a cookie if it is higher than the previous high score cookie that was saved to the browser. What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fCekQ6z8 that is the pastebin link, not sure why but it wouldn't let me put it in the original post

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE. That is the reason SO does not allow a link to code. You can change that link or it dies. Click the `<>` and post an [mcve] HERE

Comment: But first look up localStorage - and before that, search the title of your question